# How to access array field from query result in MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I got a JSON object in Cursor as follows

```
{
        "field1": "val1",
        "field2": [
            {
                "field3": "val3"
            },
            {
                "field4": "val4"
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm able to access the feild1 and its value. How to access field3 and its value?
I tried the following code but not working

```
System.out.println(cursor.next().get("field2.field3"));
```

Getting null as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example).Hope this will help.